# Multiple Join on same column

Tags: sql, join, stored-procedures

I have two tables one is the `category` table with fields as

```
id , name, created_by, created_date, modify_by, modify_date, status
```

(please note created_by & modify_by will have ids of users from user table)

and other table `user` with columns as

```
id, name, role and many more
```

I have to list category on web page with names of those users who created the new category and also those who modified the category

I am using following SQL query to get created_by user name and also modify_by user name to display in list

```
BEGIN
     SELECT cat.id,cat.name, cate.name as parentname, cat.parent_id,
     cat.created_by, cat.created_date, cat.modify_by, cat.modify_date, 
     user.firstname
     FROM `category`as cat     
     INNER JOIN `user` ON cat.created_by = user.id
     LEFT JOIN category as cate ON cate.id = cat.parent_id;
END
```

What should I add to this query to get amemodifier user n from its id which can be different from creator id?

Or do I have to write separate query for getting modifier name?

Comment: Please fix your formatting.

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If am not wrong, you need to Join `USER` table twice

```
SELECT cat.id,
       cat.NAME,
       cat.NAME   AS parentname,
       cat.parent_id,
       cat.created_by,
       cat.created_date,
       cat.modify_by,
       cat.modify_date,
       c.firstname AS created_user,
       m.firstname AS modified_user
FROM   categoryas cat
       LEFT JOIN USER c
              ON cat.created_by = c.id
       LEFT JOIN USER m
              ON cat.modify_by = m.id;
```

If the `created_by` column will never be `NULL` then you can change the `LEFT JOIN USER c` to `INNER JOIN USER c`

Answer (score 0):

Just add another user join with different table alias will do.

```
SELECT cat.id,cat.name, cate.name as parentname, cat.parent_id, 
cat.created_by, cat.created_date, cat.modify_by, cat.modify_date, 
creator.firstname creator_name, midifier.firstname modifier_name FROM 
categoryas cat INNER JOIN user creator ON 
cat.created_by = creator.id 
INNER JOIN user midifier ON 
cat.modify_by = midifier.id 
LEFT JOIN category as cate ON cate.id = cat.parent_id;
```

Comment: no it wont work i had tried it before posting here; Then it gives only one list of  category that too with same output as earlier

Comment: @Humbledust Does `modify_by` store all the modifier ids? like `1,2,3`?

Comment: it just stores that user id who is logged in to account at moment of modifying ; ID is passed using session with hidden field

Comment: @Humbledust So you want the modifiers info is right after your current output?

Answer (score 0):

You need two joins with that table with different aliases.

```
BEGIN
   SELECT cat.id,cat.name, cate.name as parentname, cat.parent_id,
   cat.created_by, cat.created_date, cat.modify_by, cat.modify_date, 
   user.firstname, modifiedUser.firstname as modifiedUser
   FROM `category`as cat
   INNER JOIN `user` ON cat.created_by = user.id
   LEFT JOIN category as cate ON cate.id = cat.parent_id;
   JOIN `user`modifiedUser ON cate.modify_by = user.id
END
```